# Initial values in scipy.integrate.solve_ivp

Tags: python, scipy, solver, ode

I'm trying to use solve_ivp but I don't understand how it deals with the initial values in the argument. The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy-integrate-solve-ivp) on solve_ivp states:

> scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(fun, t_span, y0, method='RK45', t_eval=None, dense_output=False, events=None, vectorized=False, **options)

with

> y0 : array_like, shape (n,)
>   Initial state. For problems in the complex domain, pass y0 with a complex data type (even if the initial guess is purely real)

However, I don't understand the example

```
>>> from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
>>> def exponential_decay(t, y): return -0.5 * y
>>> sol = solve_ivp(exponential_decay, [0, 10], [2, 4, 8])
>>> print(sol.t)
[  0.           0.11487653   1.26364188   3.06061781   4.85759374
   6.65456967   8.4515456   10.        ]
>>> print(sol.y)
[[2.         1.88836035 1.06327177 0.43319312 0.17648948 0.0719045
  0.02929499 0.01350938]
 [4.         3.7767207  2.12654355 0.86638624 0.35297895 0.143809
  0.05858998 0.02701876]
 [8.         7.5534414  4.25308709 1.73277247 0.7059579  0.287618
  0.11717996 0.05403753]]
```

Why do they give an array of 3 initial values here when the differential equation only has one component?

Comment: In that example, `y` will be a 1-d array with length 3.

Comment: Basically a 1d array of any length can be accepted by y as the initial value.

Answer (score 4):

> the differential equation only has one component

It doesn't. The function `exponential_decay` can accept an array as `y`, and perform operations on that array in a vectorized fashion, as is typical in NumPy.

The initial value determines how many components the unknown function has. In this case, three.